# Is it possible to create isosurfaces using Oxyplot?

Tags: c#, xamarin, heatmap, contour, oxyplot

I'm using Oxyplot HeatMapSeries for representing some graphical data.
For a new application I need to represent the data with isosurfaces, something looking like this: [image]

Some ideas around this:

- I know the ContourSeries can do the isolines, but I can't find any option that allows me to fill the gaps between lines. Does this option exists?
- I know the HeatMapSeries can be shown under the contourSeries so I can get a similar result but it does not fit our needs. [image].
- Another option wolud be limiting the HeatMapSeries colours and eliminate the interpolation. Is this possible?

If anyone has another approach to the solution I will hear it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm evaluating whether Oxyplot will meet my needs and this question interests me... from looking at the [ContourSeries source code](https://github.com/ylatuya/oxyplot/blob/master/Source/OxyPlot/Series/ContourSeries.cs), it appears to be only for finding and rendering the contour lines, but not filling the area between the lines.  Looking at [AreaSeries](https://github.com/ylatuya/oxyplot/blob/master/Source/OxyPlot/Series/AreaSeries.cs), I don't think you could just feed it contours because it is expecting two sets of points which when the ends are connected create a simple closed polygon.  The best guess I have is "rasterizing" your data so that you round each data point to the nearest contour level, then plot the heatmap of that rasterized data under the contour. The ContourSeries appears to calculate a level step that does 20 levels across the data by default.

My shortcut for doing the rasterizing based on a step value is to divide the data by the level step you want, then truncate the number with Math.Floor.

Looking at [HeatMapSeries](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/models/series/HeatMapSeries.html), it looks like you can possibly try to turn interpolation off, use a `HeatMapRenderMethod.Rectangles` render method, or supply a LinearColorAxis with fewer steps and let the rendering do the rasterization perhaps? The Palettes available for a LinearColorAxis can be seen in the [OxyPalettes source](https://github.com/dsuarezv/arduino.net/blob/master/libs/oxyplot/src/Source/OxyPlot/Rendering/OxyPalettes.cs): BlueWhiteRed31, Hot64, Hue64, BlackWhiteRed, BlueWhiteRed, Cool, Gray, Hot, Hue, HueDistinct, Jet, and Rainbow.

I'm not currently in a position to run OxyPlot to test things, but I figured I would share what I could glean from the source code and limited documentation.